# work with integer array in java

Tags: java, arrays, string, pointers

I have this string `"5,7,6,1"` and I want to make an integer array of the size 4 like this: `out={5 7 6 1}` which `out[0]=5` and `out[1]=7` and...
actually I want to have the number of the string in an integer array but when I print the `out` the output is the address of the array `out` like this: `[I@152b6651`
what's wrong with this code????

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String a = new String();
        a="5,7,6,1";
        int element, temp = 0, ans = 0,j=0;
        element = a.length() / 2 + 1;
        int[] out = new int[element];
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++) {
            if (j < element) {
                temp = (int) a.charAt(i);
                if (temp != 44) {
                    ans = ans * 10 + temp;
                } else {
                    out[j] = ans-48;
                    ans=0;
                    j++;
                }
                if(i==a.length()-1){
                    out[j] = ans-48;
                }
            }
        }
        int[] array=new int[element];
        System.out.println(out);
    }
```

Comment: use split - a.split(",")

Comment: String[] intarr = a.split(",");
    int[] n1 = new int[intarr.length];
    for(int n = 0; n < intarr.length; n++) {
       n1[n] = Integer.parseInt(parts[n]);
    }

Comment: it again shows the same result, for both intarr and n1 it shows the address of the variables!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use:

```
Integer[] out = new Integer[element];
```

then print like this:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(out));
```

Comment: tnx, yes it shows all the elements in array out but I want to do some operations on this array and all my other parameters are int, wouldn't this be hard to work with this parameter? :(

Comment: I think you can use Integer as the same way using int.